# Do I need to check type before every database request?

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, express

I am learning how to handle errors properly in Express with a Postgres database.

I have many small backend functions that I use as intermediates to interact with my database in larger functions.

Do I need to check for type before sending requests or should I send without checking and handle errors returned by the database ?

Because I have the feeling that I'm writing the same code over and over so it seems like a bad pattern but I couldn't find any answer about this online.

```
// #1 Type-checking before
export const getPerson = ({
  emailAddress,
  personID,
}: {
  emailAddress?: string;
  personID?: string;
}) => {
   // BadRequestError is a custom class that extends Error
  if (!isString(emailAddress)) throw new BadRequestError(); 
  if (!isUUID(personID)) throw new BadRequestError();
  return pool
    .query(
      `SELECT
        *
      FROM person
      WHERE ($1::citext IS NULL OR person.emailAddress = $1)
        AND ($2::uuid IS NULL OR person.person_id = $2)`,
      [emailAddress, personID]
    )
    .then((res) => res.rows)
    .catch(() => { throw new InternalServerError(); })
  };

// #2 No type-checking before, can directly return pool.then().catch()
// Seems more elegant to mebut I may lose information about which input is incorrect
// and it sends a bad request to the database

export const getPerson = ({
  emailAddress,
  personID,
}: {
  emailAddress?: string;
  personID?: string;
}) => pool
    .query(
      `SELECT
        *
      FROM person
      WHERE ($1::citext IS NULL OR person.emailAddress = $1)
        AND ($2::uuid IS NULL OR person.person_id = $2)`,
      [emailAddress, personID]
    )
    .then((res) => res.rows)
    .catch((e) => { 
      switch (e.code) {
         case '23XXX':
            throw new BadRequestError();
      }
    }
 );
```

Is #1 or #2 preferable in most cases ? Is there another common way ?

Answer (score 0):

Make types Branded (aka Opaque)

```
type uuid = string & {__type__: 'uuid'}
```

(see some library or typescript challenges github for the proper implementations)

Then if you ever have an argument if type T you don't ever chech if it's of type T, the caller should check them (as you can't assing `'qwe'` to `uuid` without `as uuid`).

---

By the way, both of examples may be incorrect if you can't pass `undefined` into the database, you should use

```
export const getPerson = ({
  emailAddress,
  personID,
}: {
  emailAddress: string;
  personID: string;
}) => ...
```

to require them being non-undefined